# My POST form is not passing data I get no error message and I am just redirected to the next page without the data being processed

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a login form:

```
<!--SIGNUP = modal_form.php-->
<!--Modal start-->
<div class="modal fade" id="enroll" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="enrollLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="enrollLabel">User signup</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="lead">Fill out this form we will get back to you</p>
                <!-- Form -->
                <form id="signup-form" class="form" method="POST" action="./includes/signup.inc.php">
                    <?php
                    $fullUrl = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";


                    if (strpos($fullUrl, "error=empty_input") == true) {
                        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert'>
                        <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should fill in on some of those fields below.
                        <button type='button' class='btn-close' data-bs-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'></button>
                    </div>";
.
.
.
.
.
                   
                        <strong>Success!</strong> Success you signed up.
                        <button type='button' class='btn-close' data-bs-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'></button>
                    </div>";
                    } else {
                        unset($_SESSION['error1']);
                    }
                    ?>

                    <div class="mb-3 input-control">
                        <label for="full-name">Full name\User name</label><br>
                        <p>*You can only have on user name per e-mail account</p>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="full-name" name="full-name"
                               placeholder="John Smith">
                        <small class="message" id="message-full-name"></small>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 input-control">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"
                               placeholder="JohnSmith@gmail.com">
                        <small class="message" id="message-email"></small>
                        <br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3 input-control">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"
                               placeholder="Password">
                        <small class="message" id="message-password"></small>
                        <br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3 input-control">
                        <label for="pwdRepeat">Password repeat</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwdRepeat" name="pwdRepeat"
                               placeholder="Retype Password">
                        <small class="message" id="message-pwdRepeat"></small>
                        <br>
                    </div>

                    <a href="./includes/reset-password-form.php">Forgot your password?</a>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" id="login-submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Register now</button>
                    </div>

                    <script src="./js/signup_error_handler.js"></script>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason it doesn't send any data to the page login.inc.php it opens that page and doesn't do anything. When i var_dump() POST it shows array() if I do the same to the input fields as in I the POST values I get null eventhough the form was filled with some value.

And this is the page to which the data is sent to:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['login-submit'])) {
    //Uzimamo podatke
    $email = $_POST["login-email"];
    $password = $_POST["login-password"];

    //Instanciranje klase SignupContr
    include "../classes/dbh.classes.php";
    include "../classes/login.classes.php";
    include "../classes/login-contr.classes.php";

    $signup = new LoginContr($email, $password);

    //Running error handlers and using signup

    $signup->loginUser();

    //Povratak na glavnu stranu

    header("location: ../index.php?error=none");
}
```

The $signup variable is the class which has all of the functions which check the input values on the servers side and if somehow the input values where empty then the user would get a message that the inputed values are empty however this message doesn't appear. When i click the login-submit button I am taken to the empty login.inc.php page and nothing happens.

Comment: There is no `login-submit` in your form, so it never enters the `if` block

Comment: can you add an else statement and echo something in it

Comment: @aynber but there is a login-submit i checked multiple times

Comment: Where? I don't see it in the code you've posted. Your submit button is named `submit`

Comment: @AlyMohamed yes I can and the else statement is always executed

Comment: Check my answer == try replacing the "login-submit' with 'password'

Comment: By the way, `name` is what gets sent to the next page, not `id`

Comment: @aynber thank you this was the problem. I delted the name part and thought that id sends to the next page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, I can't find anything with `login-submit` as a `name` property.
Maybe check if `isset($_POST["password"])` or "email" or anything that is IN your form.

Because no `login-submit` is in your form, the if condition is never met.

`name` property is the thing that gets sent over not `id`. I see the issue you made. You need to remove the prefix: `login-` from the $_POST methods. Your `name` properties are only: password, email, submit, etc.